# Rewrite Rules in separate config file

Tags: asp.net, configuration, url-rewriting, web-config

I am using URL rewriting in my application, I have two config file as given below, first one have configuration and second one have for Rules. but I am getting 404 Error.

**Web Config**

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rewriteMaps configSource="rewritemaps.config"></rewriteMaps>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

**rewritemaps.config File**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules> 

        <rule name="RewriteURLHometPaging" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^Home" />
          <action appendQueryString="false" type="Rewrite" url="Default.aspx" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="RedirectURLHomePaging" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^Default\.aspx$" />
          <action appendQueryString="false" type="Redirect" url="Home" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="RedirectURLContactPaging" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^Contact-Us\.aspx$" />
          <action appendQueryString="false" type="Redirect" url="Contactus" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="RewriteURLContactPaging" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^Contactus" />
          <action appendQueryString="false" type="Rewrite" url="Contact-Us.aspx" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="RedirectURLAboutPaging" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^About-Us\.aspx$" />
          <action appendQueryString="false" type="Redirect" url="About" />
        </rule>

        <rule name="RewriteURLAboutPaging" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^About" />
          <action appendQueryString="false" type="Rewrite" url="About-Us.aspx" />
        </rule>

      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Error Screenshot is here: [image: Error Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

Multiple Config Files

The appSettings element can contain a file attribute that points to an external file. It will change web.config file to look like the following:

```
<appSettings/>

<connectionStrings/>

<system.web>

    <compilation debug="false" strict="false" explicit="true" />

</system.web>

<appSettings file="externalSettings.config"/>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to create an external file with one or more rewrite maps (source [ruslany.net](https://ruslany.net/2010/05/storing-url-rewrite-mappings-in-a-separate-file/)).

You could also use this technique for creating an external file for rewrite rules. See the end the full post on ruslany.net linked above.

**Web.config:**

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rewriteMaps configSource="MyRewriteMaps.config"></rewriteMaps>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Redirect rule for MyRedirects">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
          <add input="{MyRedirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
      </rule>
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**MyRewriteMaps.config:**

```
<rewriteMaps>
  <rewriteMap name="MyRedirects">
    <add key="/oldurl" value="/newurl" />
    <add key="/otheroldurl" value="/othernewurl" />
  </rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```